# "I was made to laugh"

Tags: usage, infinitives, bare-infinitives

We know that we use bare infinitive with certain verbs like *make*.

> I made him laugh. (Active voice)

> He was made to laugh by me. (Passive voice)

Why is the bare infinitive used in the active voice and an infinitive is used in the passive voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I made him* [*laugh*].
>
> *He was made* [*to laugh by me*].

These are both catenative constructions in which the bracketed non-finite clauses are complement of the catenative verb "make".

A few catenative verbs take bare infinitivals, including the causatives "make", "have" and "let".

In the case of "make", "to" is restricted to the passive.

I don't know why "make" licenses bare infintivals in active clauses and only *to*-infinitivals in passives; it's just a fact of English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to remember that active voice verbs which can be made passive must all be *transitive* verbs, meaning they have at least one object.  In the example you provide, the object is "him."

When converted to a passive-voice construction, the object from the active-voice verb becomes the subject, and a passive-voice verb has no object.  This changes the grammatical structure.

Consider:

- I made **him** laugh.
- **He** *was* made **to** laugh.

Notice that the pronoun has also changed form.  As a subject pronoun, "he" must be followed by a verb.  In this case, "was made" is that verb, which is continued by the infinitive "to laugh."  The requirement for chaining additional verbs, in their infinitive form, is that "to" is included.

Consider:

"I would like **to** go **to** study **to** learn **to** be a doctor."

After "would like," the primary verb, the added infinitive verbs all must have "to."

But when "him" is the pronoun, it is the objective case, and no verb is expected to follow.  The "laugh" is not actually attached to "him": it is connected to "made," functioning as a two-word *separable* verb (a phrasal verb) in which the object is inserted between.  In other words, the verb is "to make laugh" (NOT "to make to laugh").  This is why there is no "to" before "laugh."  A two-word separable verb, with an object between, *cannot* maintain that object when converted to passive voice because a passive-voice verb cannot take an object.

It is less common for two-word verbs (phrasal verbs) to have both words be actual verbs, and far more common for the second word to be a preposition or adverb.  In those cases where the second word is not itself a verb, "to" would be unnecessary because it could not form an infinitive.  In the case of "make laugh," however, both words are verbs, which, when separated by their object do not have "to," but without an object must be chained as separate verbs, and not as a two-word verb.  It's one of those two-word verbs which *must* be separated by its object.

Comment: The term 'two word separable verb' is misleading since it implies that the combination concerned forms a syntactic constituent belonging to the category verb, which is not true. "Make laugh" is always two distinct verbs, where "laugh" (or “to laugh” in passives) serves as catenative complement of "make". Thus, in _I made him laugh_, "him" is the syntactic object of "made", and the infinitival clause "laugh" is complement of "made". And in the passive _He was made to laugh_ "made to laugh" is complement of "was" and "to laugh" is complement of "made".

Comment: @BillJ I will respectfully differ.  I understand that this grammatical construction is uncommon in English, but I see it as still just as much present as the subjunctive past tense--not yet extinct.  In other languages, like Greek and Hebrew, there is a class of verbs called "causative" (Hebrew does not technically have verb "tenses").  In English, this "causative" is formed by the addition of "make" to the verb which represents the action, in this case "make (someone) laugh" means "cause (someone) to laugh."

Comment: I'm aware that "make" is causative in the examples in question; that is not in dispute. What I'm disputing is your use of the terms "two-word separable verb" /  two-word verb'. The grammar of the clauses can only be as I outlined in my last comment.

Comment: @BillJ What else would you call it?  It is not as if "make" is a helping verb.  It functions in exactly the same manner as that of a two-word verb.  The verb is not "make": it is "make laugh," and the object gets placed between these two words.  Other examples of this causative form might be: "make X go" (we would never say "make to go" _him_, but rather make _him_ go); "make X fail"; "make X boil"; "make X rise" (e.g. make _the price_ rise).  In all of these, the object must be sandwiched between the two words of the verb, and the object pertains to _both_ of the words, not just to "make".

Comment: I explained the syntax in detail in my first comment. I'm inclined to think that I should have made it clearer that these are catenative constructions.

Comment: @BillJ The problem here is that this new-fangled "grammar" does not match what I was carefully taught in school.  The dictionary itself appears incorrect in its classification of the parts of speech when defining "catenative" as: "denoting a verb that governs a nonfinite form of another verb, for example _like_ in 'I _like_ swimming.' "  The word "swimming" in that sentence is not a verb: it is a _gerund noun_.  I, therefore, do not even find support for the concept of "catenative constructions."  It seems to be a whole different grammar than has been traditionally taught.

Comment: I accept that the catenative construction can be tricky to grasp; nevertheless, it is widely accepted by linguists and grammarians, and has been for as long as I can remember.. The dictionary you quoted from is not quite right. In 'I like swimming" the word "swimming" is strictly speaking ambiguous, but verb is the more salient interpretation (“I like to swim”). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional swimming". This is where grammar gets interesting!

Comment: General comment: One has to be careful when comparing grammar across languages as constructions that are similar in some respects will be different in other respects. Some grammatical traditions emphasize common terminology across languages, while others emphasize distributional criteria within a single language.

Comment: Perhaps a useful analogy to this construction is _Reporters saw them leave_ / _They were seen leaving_ (_?They were seen to leave_). I'm not sure what is gained by thinking of "see" + "leave" as a separable verb.